# Modify attributes of plot after beeing created

Tags: plotting

I have a complex plot of which’s calculation took quite a long time.
Is it possible afterwards to modify certain attributes of the plot without the necessity to calculate it again?

Example:

```
p = Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 2 Pi}];
```

Question: 
How can I access and modify directly `p` to e.g. set `PlotLabel` of `p`, or some other attributes?

Comment: the following seems to work (to my surprise!) `p[[2]]//FullForm` displays the `Plot` options used for plotting; you could pick an option that is already present and replace it with something like eg `p/.(DisplayFunction->Identity)->Sequence[DisplayFunction->Identity,PlotLabel->"just arrived!"]`; if the option you want to change is already present then you can replace that directly eg `p/.(PlotLabel->__)->(PlotLabel->"just arrived!")`

Comment: @user42582: thanks ... also this works: `p /. (DisplayFunction -> Identity) -> Sequence[PlotLabel -> "j‌​ust arrived!"]` ... please put your comment as an answer.

Comment: @mrz `Show[p, PlotLabel -> "whatever"]`

Comment: @mrz you wouldn't want to do that because you would effectively *not* include the `DisplayFunction->Identity` option which is not what you want to do

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/69159/discussion-on-question-by-mrz-modify-attributes-of-plot-after-beeing-created).